# Using maphilight for total beginners?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use a jquery plugin called maphilight.
I'm totally new to using jquery plugins. I've a fair bit of experience with other web designing coding and even a little with javascript but actually trying to practically use it like this...its a first.

I just can't get this plugin to work.
On my map the different areas are correctly clickable and serve as links however they won't become hilighted. The best I can do is an inccorect highlight shows up in a differnt part of the page.

I've looked at the maphighlight site and saw his examples but I cant see a solid how to use the code example.

Near the top of my page I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/maphilight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.mapHiLight').maphilight({ stroke: false, fillColor: '009DDF', fillOpacity: 1 });
    });
</script>
```

then for the map

```
<img src="image/japan.svg" width="570" height="750" usemap="#nihon">
    <map name="nihon">
    <area id="test3" href="http://www.tokyo.com" shape="poly" coords="407.963,498.081 403.323,498.08 407.963,498.081 400.819,498.908 387.434,499.66 388.25,496.5 
                381.4,492.742 381.742,489.948 381.742,489.948 382.811,488.967 385.754,488.459 395.005,491.437 412.248,488.907 412.049,492.742" alt="tests" title="testerhi">
    </map>
```

what could be going wrong here? What should I do?

Sorry for being so clueless here. I hope I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Commas!
Commas are the problem!
The SVG itself doesn't have commas in the co-ords and I just copy and pasted that but for some reason jquery demands commas. Works perfectly with commas replacing spaces in the coords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have given class `mapHiLight` to your image.
Here is a sample demo for maphilight.

Sample Demo Here : [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k67gq/6/)

Comment: ah, thanks, that has got highlights showing. Its in the wrong place somehow though.
http://i41.tinypic.com/2zjfkaq.jpg
Is an image. My mouse is over the area to the right of the black area (which is naturally painted that way). The red area too is naturally painted that way.
You can see one co-ordinate seems correct but all the others...less so